# How will the client of a Web Service consuming a DoTNET vs JAVA wsdl differ?

Tags: java, .net, web-services

How will the client of a Web Service consuming a DoTNET vs JAVA wsdl differ?

Also, is it correct in stating that the dot NET WS invokes the constructor of the WS on each operation invocation whereas a JAVA WS has its constructor called only once when the application server starts up!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of web services (WSDL) is that in theory there should be no difference in the specific technology.

In practice that statement only holds as long as the web service does not expose 'exotic' data types (e.g. in .Net, the web service should not expose DataSets which are very .Net specific, and make the service probably not useable in non-.Net clients)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it a client of a web service should not care one way or the other what technology powers the service.